# Android AlarmManager setting an alarm for the next day

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I've an application that sets alarms at specific times specified with a TimePicker (24-hour mode).

I've noticed that if the time is e.g. 23:00 and you set an alarm for 01:00, the AlarmManager interprets this as an already passed date. Currently, I set my alarms like the following:

```
private void setUpAlarm(int hour, int minute){
    long timeInMs = 0;
    long currentTimeInMs = 0;
    long timeDifference = 0;

    // Set up a calendar to calculate when the alarm should go off
    Calendar customCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    customCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    customCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    customCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    customCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Date customDate = customCalendar.getTime();

    timeInMs = customDate.getTime();
    currentTimeInMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timeDifference = timeInMs - currentTimeInMs;

    /*
     * If the user has entered a date that has passed (time difference is negative)
     * add 24 hours to the alarm time.
     */
    if(timeDifference < 0){
        timeInMs += 86400000;
    }

    //set the alarm
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmClockRingRing.class);
    action = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int)timeInMs,
            intent, 0); 
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMs, action);
    Toast.makeText(this, "One shot alarm set at " + alarmTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

As you can see the app calculate the time difference and if it's negative it sets the alarm for the next day. This creates the bug described above. How to fix it?

Regards,

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem though, I managed to change my approach, instead of using

```
customCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
customCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
customCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
customCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

I changed it to

```
customCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
customCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, diffHours);
customCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, diffMinutes);
customCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
customCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

get `diffHours` and `diffMinutes` like this

```
diffHours   = timeDifference / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
diffMinutes = timeDifference / (60 * 1000) % 60;
```

If the user has selected the same current time, not a past date or a future date, it means he wants the alarm to be fired 24 hours later so:

```
if (timeDifference == 0) {
    diffHours = 24;
}
```

What If I want to manage days as well? do this

```
diffDays = timeDifference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

then convert days to hours like this

```
if (diffDays != 0) {
    diffHours = diffHours + (diffDays * 24);
}
```

Also change your:

```
if (timeDifference < 0) {
    timeInMs += 86400000;
}
```

to:

```
if (timeDifference < 0) {
    timeDifference += 86400000;
}
```

And your:

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMs, action);
```

To:

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, customCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), action);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a note...

If you use something other than `RTC_WAKEUP` or `RTC`, you cannot use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

**E.g.** **ELAPSED_TIME** uses `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP